# Reducing the time taken to convert a data set to a given list of objects

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, foreach

I have a stored procedure which returns a Data Set. I debugged and noticed that it doesn't take that much of time to execute the Stored Procedure.

But I need to assign the data set returned to a collection of objects.

I have shown below how I do it.
when I debugged something I noticed was that it takes a considerable amount of time to execute the foreach loop.

```
            var ds = Handler.GetDataSetFromSP();

            foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                MyModel model = new MyModel();

                model.Code = row["TextOne"].ToString();
                model.Name = row["TextTwo"].ToString();
                model.SomeOtherCol = row["TextThree"].ToString();
                model.AnotherCol = row["TextFour"].ToString();
                model.NextCol= row["TextFive"].ToString();
                model.FinalCol = Convert.ToDateTime(row["TextSix"]);

                accounts.Add(model);
            }
```

Is there an alternative way to write the code segment given in the above foreach loop ?
It takes a lot of time and I need to get it reduced.

Comment: Do you have indexes in your columns ?

Comment: how much time doea it takes to convert the data and for how many records? and how much time does it takes to get the records from the database?

Comment: No. I don't. But the SP gets called in the line "var ds = Handler.GetDataSetFromSP();" and it gets executed in like 2 seconds.

Comment: when you execute Stored Procedure use Statement.setFetchSize(some number here) . This might help you to improve performance

Comment: There are 7081 records. It can go beyond that number. It takes 30-35 (approximately) seconds to execute the foreach loop

Comment: Do you need all rows?

Comment: yes, I do need all the rows

Comment: Did you tried `SqlDataReader` instead of returning the `DataSet`? Looping the `SqlDataReader` is considerably fast than looping through `DataSet.Tables[0].Rows`

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30714/faster-way-to-convert-datatable-to-list-of-class This might help. Please have a look.

Comment: @nidarshanifernando: 1) I'd return `IDataReader` from `GetDataSetFromSP` instead of `DataSet` to avoid unnecessary overhead; 2) after replacing `DS` to `IDataReader`, I'd use profiler to determine, which line is slow.